# checking values inside functions vs outside?

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I personally always checked values inside the function using them but at our University, a teacher wants us to always check values outside functions. I think it could be a good idea to check one time values outside a function if we are gonna call the function several times with the same checked values. However, if you forget to check critical values, it could give you errors like a Segmentation Fault in your program.

I have pasted code I was working on. At school we should be checking values outside functions but I think this is crazy and a waste of time in this case. The main function is at the end of the code, you can see the difference when checking return value of malloc (init_unsecure outside the function and init_secure inside the function) or when checking if an element exists before removing it (remove_unsecure outside the function who duplicates a while loop in exists function and remove_secure inside the function).

What do you think? Doesn't it look obvious checking values inside functions?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct  strens
{
  int       v[100];
  int       n;
}       StrEns, *Ens;

// init struct pointer (need to check if return value is not NULL)
Ens init_unsecure()
{
  Ens   e;

  if ((e = malloc(sizeof(StrEns))) != NULL)
    e->n = 0;
  return e;
}

// init struct pointer and check if malloc is not NULL
Ens init_secure()
{
  Ens   e;

  if ((e = malloc(sizeof(StrEns))) == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  e->n = 0;
  return e;
}

// insert element
Ens insert(Ens e, int x)
{
  e->v[e->n] = x;
  ++e->n;
  return e;
}

// return if element exists or not
int exists(Ens e, int x)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < e->n && e->v[i] != x)
    ++i;
  return (i != e->n);
}

// remove element (need to check if element exists before)
Ens remove_unsecure(Ens e, int x)
{
  --e->n;
  int i = 0;
  while (e->v[i] != x)
    ++i;
  e->v[i] = e->v[e->n];
}

// remove element if exists
Ens remove_secure(Ens e, int x)
{
  --e->n;
  int i = 0;
  while (i < e->n && e->v[i] != x)
    ++i;
  e->v[i] = e->v[e->n];
}

// comparing init_unsecure vs init_secure && remove_unsecure vs remove_secure
int main()
{
  Ens   e1, e2, e3;

  if ((e1 = init_unsecure()) == NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  if ((e2 = init_unsecure()) == NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  if ((e3 = init_unsecure()) == NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  e1 = init_secure();
  e2 = init_secure();
  e3 = init_secure();

  if (exists(e1, 42))
    remove_unsecure(e1, 42);
  if (exists(e2, 42))
    remove_unsecure(e2, 42);
  if (exists(e3, 42))
    remove_unsecure(e3, 42);

  remove_secure(e1, 42);
  remove_secure(e2, 42);
  remove_secure(e3, 42);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The (still) prevailing mindset in C programming is that the caller of your functions knows what he is doing and should therefore supply valid arguments. Failure to do so is widely accepted to be a reason for undefined behaviour.

For example, `free` doesn't have to validate whether the pointer you are passing has been previously returned by `malloc` because that would affect the performance. As long as the code that calls your functions is correct and supplies each argument within the expected ranges, everything should be OK even without defensive checking inside the functions.

It is still advisable, though, to have assertions throughout your code so that you as a programmer are able to catch anomalies as early as possible.

Comment: you right, i agree... The tool doesn't use the user. the user uses the tool. ;)

Comment: So you would not check values at all, considering there is no error. As long as there is not user input maybe, what would you do then? For example the user gives a number to remove as argument. If you don't want an infinite loop, you have to check if it exists or check inside the function that i < e->n. Then, checking inside function is better, you agree? cc @JoeDF

Comment: When it comes to user input, you should always be validating it. The code that handles the input should most likely be validating it, while the other parts of the program are designed to be efficient and usable regardless of having user input or not.

Comment: ok but I don't understand how if (exists(e1, 42)) remove_unsecure(e1, 42); can be more efficient than remove_secure(e1, 42); When using exists function you have a while loop and then remove_unsecure has one too. With remove_secure it can check all-in-one.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev &baptx : you both have some good points, but it all depends on what you're in the function... for a simple example..
lets says strlen(), checking if the first element is null vs a loop is better.. or for example there are also references to "Undefined behavior" in the standard definition of c/c++, etc. which implies that the function does not check if that is valid input... so, i yes say, that you are both right, but it really depends on what you're doing. ;)

Comment: @baptx about the last comment you made, that is like high-level languages versus low-level languages. :)

Comment: @JoeDF yes, I think it depends too and in the main I have provided, I don't see why I would use _unsecure functions if it will duplicate code when I need to check values.